# React-Redux's connect() method throwing TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Working on the Dan Abramov's excellent tutorial for Redux, and on chap 27 - *Generating containers with connect()* - a strange bug is occurring:

First I define these two functions:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
   };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      onTodoClick: (id) => {
         dispatch({
            type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
            id
         })
      }
   }
}
```

Then I import the necessary dependency:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

Then I create my component using the method exposed from react-redux, and pass in the two functions, finally connecting to my other component, `TodoList`.

```
const VisibleTodoList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

When I do this, it causes the browser to fail to render and the console returns:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined`

I have never come across this error before, and it seems specific to the `connect()` method of `react-redux`.

Has anyone come across this before, and/or know what could be causing it?

---

UPDATE:

`getVisibleTodos` is defined above. If its `TodoList` you want to see...

```
const TodoList = ( {todos, onTodoClick} ) => (
   <ul>
      {todos.map(todo =>
         <Todo key={todo.id}
            {...todo}
            onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
         />
      )}
   </ul>
)
```

Comment: Please show us what `getVisibleTodos` is doing.

Comment: Please see update

Comment: what is you `TodoList` react class? is it imported or defined properly?

Comment: like @Zack Tanner says, please show us `getVisibleTodos`

Comment: @Zack Tanner and @Pineda, `getVisibleTodos` is defined as the `connect()` method which passes mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps, and then connects to another component, in this case `TodoList`. So I already have shown you `getVisibleTodos`.

Comment: The function itself is not defined in your post, but glad to see it was resolved.

Comment: @Zack Tanner I've noticed I put a typo in my update - `VisibleTodos` instead of `VisibleTodoList` - is this the source of the confusion? Otherwise all the info is there as far as I can see. The function is defined in my post: `const VisibleTodoList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList)`. Sorry to be persistent, but just curious why my comment has been downmarked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably defining the `TodoList` component *after* your call to `connect`.  Unlike the `var` keyword, the ES6 keywords like `let`, `const`, and `class` do *not* get hoisted to the top of the scope, and only exist starting at the line they're declared on.  So, if you call `connect()` before you've defined `TodoList`, you're effectively running `connect()(undefined)`.  It's also possible that you might have an import statement that's not correct, which could also result in `TodoList` being undefined.

See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/253 for some further discussion.

Comment: You're a legend. That was it! Also, really useful to know that ES6 variable keywords don't hoist, wasn't aware of that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sure.  Yeah, the block scoping is actually the main reason for `let` and `const` to exist, but it can be a bit of a surprise for people.  FYI, I have a list of articles on [ES6 features](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/es6-features.md) as part of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links), which you might find helpful.